# Replays freeze/don't work after upgrading to Windows 8!

Tags: starcraft-2

Originally I ran StarCraft 2 on Windows Vista and everything worked fine.

A couple of months ago, however, I upgraded my PC to Windows 8. I run Starcraft 2 without any issues, but replays now are working very bad; after 2-3 minutes of playing (usually on x2, x4, x8 speed) it hangs for a while. During the hang-time music is still playing, but the game in fact is frozen. It restores in 30-40~ seconds and after a while it hangs again.

How can I solve this problem?

*However, upon my upgrading to windows 8 I didn't re-install StarCraft 2. Do I need to?*

Comment: If you upgraded Windows Vista to Windows 8 then you should have had to reinstall ALL your applications since NONE of your applications are transfered over.  **Its also entirely possible this is a hardware issue and has nothing to do with Windows 8**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact problem was not with Windows version. Problem was in SSD. Due to some reasons game perform some disk loading operations and because of particular SSD model it become slower and slower. I've observed similar problems with other applications.

Replacement of SSD (M500 model instead of V4) resolved problem IN FULL.

See more details on that here: https://superuser.com/questions/570416/ssd-works-slow-under-windows-8

Answer (score 3):

You should

**a) Reinstall SC2** 
or 
 **b) [Contact the blizzard support via ticket](https://us.battle.net/support/en/ticket/status)**

Often times they can help you regardless of whether it is a known issue or not.
(*You can write a ticket from your battle.net Account and can also check, if there is a similar problem there*)

Comment: Ok, thanks, will try to submit report to blizzard and see if/what they recommend.

Answer (score 0):

What helped is full Windows 8 re-installation. Potentially, problem could be that my previous version of windows was 'developer edition'. I installed the standard one and now everything is fine. Don't know what exactly happened, may be it just pulled better drivers for my SSD...