# Why does Starcraft 2 get slower as a match progresses?

Tags: starcraft-2, technical-issues

The problem is simple, I fear the solution is unobtainable.

Whenever I get (roughly) more than 120 supply my game comes to almost a complete standstill. Playing ladder makes me cry a little inside. I need it to not to lag at all. It's not the connection as playing campaign gives me the same problem. Currently all graphics are set to their very lowest.

```
My Rig:
Windows 7 b 64-bit
Intel core i7 3.5gh
16 GB of RAM (DDR3-2133 (G Skill RipjawsZ F3-17000CL9-4GBZH))
Radeon Dual-X R9 280x 3GB
448gb SSD Samsung
1000w PSU
```

I've overclocked a bit to get some extra juice out of this badboy. Sadly, in SC this makes no difference.

I can play any other game for fun, Thief is the newest one I've tried out all on maximum.

Running latest drivers and versions of everything.

[image: Cropped screenshot of CPU-Z output]

Comment: The specs of that thing *should* not lagg/slowdown at *all*. I don't own the game so can't help with looking for the source. Is it the graphics who come to a standstill or everything in the game while you keep your fps? Or both?

Comment: Just the FPS sadly, mouse works work, CPU and Ram are not even at 40%. No real heat and the GC is barely working...

Comment: much as Arperum said your machine should be able to run SC2 without even breaking a sweat. You say this is the ONLY game this problem occurs? If thats the case try doing a clean install of the game and see where that gets you, maybe the files are just corrupted.

Comment: I have experienced similar issues. My PC is of similar specs and I have had this happen to me as well. Battlenet Issue? Network Issue? DirectX Issue?

Comment: I would hit the battle.net forums up, Blizzard games often do not play well with SPECIFIC peices of hardware, IE: Graphics Card XY. Also update your video card drivers.

Comment: Did your machine run SCII without problems in the past? It may have been a recent patch.

Comment: All good points, I have tried the repair tool withing the starup tool of SC, this returned no errors. Prior to this I also did a fresh install no fix. Bnet, Network issue, 100% no. DirectX interesting idea. I will play with this.  malware...It could be, but to only target SC2? Indeed, only SC2 is the problem, nothing else.

Comment: @JamieHutber or it only shows on SC2 and not with any other game you have

Comment: @ratchetfreak Had a good hour conversation with the blizzard technical support via live chat. We didn't fix it, but using `Fullscreen` rather than `Fullscreen (windowed)` added about 20fps. Still, I got to 1 FPS during battles.

Comment: What happens if you disable Crossfire?  I know I've heard of similar issues in the past, though I thought those problems were fixed by now.

Comment: I'm pretty sure crossfire isn't turned on? Crossfire is when you have multiple cards, basically AMD's version of SLI? I'm new to the AMD world :D

Comment: are you sure starcraft is using you GC instead of the integrated/software graphics?

Comment: It's turned off in my device manager. I assume this is enough. Interestingly i can run thief at the same time flawlessly.

Comment: Jus tto update, I did reinstall my directX to the latest version. Even though it already was this version. it can't hurt right. So thoughts on Ram problems? Memtest said nothing was wrong, but I'm temped to go and buy some ram and test it out.

Comment: I think the same as @ratchetfreak. We don't know about your GC neither your mainboard but, The integrated chipset on mine is capable of rendering SC2 properly while the game is at its beggining. After a while, it becomes completly lost. Your case really sounds like SC2 doesn't use your GC.

Comment: plus that you can run another game at the same time is a large clue...

Comment: your graphic card settings are def. wrong. inside of sc2 or on your machine.

Comment: I suggest you ask in the blizzard forums for this. The blizzard tech support will help you eventually.

Comment: I agree with Bloodcount - ask in an official Blizzard forum! I think you can run a tool that sends a report to Blizzard alongside your notes on the problem. And it does sound like your SSdrive is the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had different but similar issue: problem was related to SSD drive.

See more details here in SC2 topic: [Replays freeze/don't work after upgrading to Windows 8!](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/102979/replays-freeze-dont-work-after-upgrading-to-windows-8/165757#165757)

and in superuser site topic:
https://superuser.com/questions/570416/ssd-works-slow-under-windows-8/746207#746207

Eventually, my claims to manufacturer was satisfied and I got credit for my SSD. I got around 60% of original price though.

I would recommend you to run diagnostic tool and if version confirmed - talk to manufacturer for replacement with another model/money back or store credit.

Comment: Which tool did you use to check the drive :) I recently upgraded to a 448ssd.

Comment: See the title on my screenshots: that's Crystal Disk Mark. Notice: I not only used that. Another thing I did when I spoke with support I showed them screenshots made from Windows8 task manager which indicated that SSD was BUSY 100%, but barely processing requests... Use all tools you can and convince those guys either give money back, give credit, or replace with ANOTHER model (check which model will work 1st though).

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, your graphics system is not the bottleneck, none of your hardware is. You may notice that you experience almost the exact same slowdown with low or high graphics settings.

It's something interfering frequently with your CPU's active process. Probably malware, but possibly non-malicious antivirus or network checking software.

In task manager, disable all processes except the ones that crash your computer, and try running the game.

Answer (score 0):

A very possible issue that can occur is that your CPU or GPU is not boosting properly; more likely it is your GPU.

I had an HD 7870 and I was playing Dead Island, noticed that I was getting 25% of my normal FPS, and checked out my GPU-z. My core clock was stuck at 300 MHz as if the GPU was idling. The normal speed is 1000 MHz.

I simply had to restart my PC and the problem went away but your situation might involved a different fix.

Anyways, check your boost speeds and make sure they are being hit during gameplay.